# HL2 sleep settings

Tags: hololens

I am building a tool for HL2.

I am using the command below to set the sleep settings in HL2 through my tool.

"https://127.0.0.1:10443/api/power/cfg/SCHEME_CURRENT/SUB_SLEEP/STANDBYIDLE?ValueAC=1800&ValueDC=1800";

After running the above command, in the device portal, I can see that both on battery and plugged in values are set to 30 min, as expected.
Though my device goes to sleep after few min, maybe 3 or 5 minutes.

If I set the settings manually through the device portal, then everything works as expected, the device goes to sleep after 30 min.
Is there sth in the command that I am using wrong?
In HL1 it seems like it is working, but not in HL2.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The web interface uses the same REST APIs.  I would recommend enabling the Developer Tools in your browser (e.g., F12) and looking at the network requests when changing the value in the web page.  There are multiple requests that happen when changing the sleep settings.  Your automated call should follow that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the sleep settings, the Device Portal makes these POST requests:

```
.../api/power/cfg/SCHEME_CURRENT/SUB_SLEEP/STANDBYIDLE?ValueAC=180&ValueDC=600
.../api/power/cfg/SCHEME_CURRENT/SUB_VIDEO/VIDEOIDLE?ValueAC=180&ValueDC=600
.../api/power/activecfg?scheme=SCHEME_CURRENT
```

You should make the same requests in your tool. Just replace the values (180 and 600) with your own.